# wireshark - install stable and development builds in OS X

Tags: macos, installation, wireshark

How can I install both (at the time of writing) `1.12.5` and `1.99.6` in OS X 10.8.5?

AFAIK Wireshark installs to the `kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier` path.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of answers I tried the following. I installed the stable release `1.12.5` first and moved the application bundle to the trash, then I installed the dev version `1.99.6` and renamed the app bundle 'Wireshark [dev build]', next moved the older version from the trash to the applications folder. So far both are working. `ChmodBPF` and `wireshark` CLI utility launcher didn't changed. I didn't notice any problems in the install scripts, but I might be wrong.